# How to filter angular list programatically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm wondering how could I filter angular list programatically.

I'm working on project and I need to filter subcategories by clicking on categorie.

For example by clicking on Drinks I need to display: Coke, Fanta, Pepsi...

And by clicking on group I'm filtering subgroups and it works, but I want to set it manually when .html is loaded for example to make same effect like user pressed on categorie..

Here is my code:

```
 filteredSubGroups: Group[];



 ngOnInit() {
    // Here I get values from DB and when I console.log them, they are there, so this is allright.

    this.groups = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['groups'];
    this.subGroups = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['subGroups'];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectedId = '78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53';
    // setTimeout(() => { // set time out to avoid error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked
    //  this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId === "78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53");
    //}, 5);

    // Here is list which is source to my subcategories  
    this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId === "78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53");
  }
```

And here is my template:

```
<li *ngFor="let subgroup of filteredSubGroups">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="" data-target="" class="btn categories-btn" (click)="getArticlesByGroupId(subgroup.id)" [class.active]="subgroup.id == selectedSubId">
            {{subgroup.title | uppercase}}
        </button>
    </li>
```

But when I run application I get next error:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf:
>   undefined'. Current value: 'ngForOf: [object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object]'.
>       at viewDebugError (core.js:9817)
>       at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9795)
>       at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9962)
>       at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:14010)
>       at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13984)
>       at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14813)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14715)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyComponent.html:38)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
>       at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13822)

Edit:

[image]

By clicking on main categories, subcategories are shown:

```
  <li *ngFor="let group of groups;let isFirst = first" (click)="filterSubgroupsByGroupId(group.id)">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#food" class="btn xbutton-square" [class.active]="group.id == selectedId">
        <i [class]="getClass(group.image)" [innerHTML]="getUnicode(group.image)"></i>
      </button>
    </li>
```

And I just wanted to show categories manually / programmatically when app is runned, without really clicking on category.. and after that user can click wherever he wants..

Comment: Why are you filtering on afterViewInit? You already have your subGroups onInit, so just filter it there.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I might lost original values? and how that might looks if I would filter it onInit?

Comment: You get this problem because when your component was initialized your filteredSubGroups was undefined. Now you are using filteredSubGroups in your template and after your view is initialized (afterViewInit) you are changing the value. Hence angular is warning that after the view was initialized, the value of filteredSubGroups has changed. So it wants you to run the digest cycle again to pick up the new values

Comment: @VinodBhavnani Can you post example how this might work correct so I may accept it as answer! Thanks for help

Comment: So you could run the angular digest cycle again by using ChangeDetectorReference and calling detectChanges(), but that is not advisable. So you should somehow get the values for filteredSubGroups before your view has initialized. Hence I said, put this line this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId === "78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53"); after your get subGroups onInit

Comment: I have written it as an answer. Please see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngAfterContentInit`, it's should works

Comment: A crapy solution could be to put the call un a timeout:
  setTimeout({
      this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId === "78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53");
  });

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how it should be:

1) import changeDetectorReference from Angular/core
2) inject it into the constructor like this

```
constructor (cdr: ChangeDetectorReference){}

filteredSubGroups: Group[];



 ngOnInit() {
    this.groups = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['groups'];
    this.subGroups = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['subGroups'];
    this.selectedId = '78ebcad8-8cb0-4172-8cd8-bb6fb6b3bf53';
    this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId === this.selectedId);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

So now you have your filteredSubGroups before your view is initialized. Hence the error will no longer appear.

Comment: still it's not working but issues are not there in console, only first time when app is runned. Check for Edit, I've posted an image how my code looks, and console.log as you can see, values are there indeed..

Comment: Ok so are you saying that your dropdown filter is not working?

Comment: Try to remove all code from ngOnInit and put it in constructor

Comment: It is not dropdown filter, there are categories and by clicking on them subcategories are shown, and if I move it to contructor I'm getting Cannot read property 'filter' of null

Comment: I've tried even before, and that didn't worked also for me, values were there in console.log() but not visible on html.. : (

Comment: is that really hard to make this work, I'm so dissapointed :/